# Post form does not submit data entered by client-Thanks for your assistance

Tags: forms, post

Here is the coding that we have for visitors to post their informations; 
When visitor clicks on "submit", visitor sees a Thank you page.(works fine)

Our problem is that the data entered by visitor is not recorded on the "requests.php" page we created.

Thank you so much for any help to solve this and allow us to collect the data on the requests.php form and have this form saved each time.

```
    <div class="content">

    <form action="requests.php" method="POST"> 

    header('Location: thank_you.php')

    <strong>&iquest;Qu&eacute; limusina usted queria comprar?</strong><br>

    <textarea name="Comments" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

    <br>

    <br>

     <p><strong>Su Informaci&oacute;nes (Importante): Click sobre     
     &quot;Submit&quot; al fin cuando usted ha terminado:</strong></p>

     <br>

     <strong>Su nombre</strong><br>

     <input name="Name" value size="50">

      <br>

      <br>

      <strong>Pa&iacute;s y Ciudad</strong><br>

      <input name="Country" value size="50">

      <br>

      <br>

      <strong>Compan&iacute;a (Importante)</strong><br>

      <input name="Company" value size="50">

      <br>

      <br>

      <strong>Tel&eacute;fono</strong><br>

      <input name="Telephone" value size="50">

      <br>

      <br>

      <strong>E-Mail</strong><br>

       <input name="EMail" value size="50">

       <br>

       <br>

       <strong>&iquest;Cuando usted quiere comprar su Limusina?</strong><br>

        <input name="When_need_limo" value size="50">

        <br>

        <br>

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> 

         </form>

         </div> <!-- end main div -->
```

Comment: Please provide your code for requests.php or we can't help debug it.

Comment: ok thanks, tried to put the code and it shows the webpage almost? do i need to put the code in brackets?

Comment: There are code tags in the editor. You highlight the code, and push them. They look like `{ }`

Comment: basically visitors can input their info on the page, click and submit and see the thank you page.

Problem is their data are not registered on the "requests.php" page.
thanks.

Comment: There is still no code from `requests.php`.  I'm also not sure why `header('Location: thank_you.php')` is sitting in the HTML code, as that is PHP.

Comment: the "requests.php" page has this for code:
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$Country = $_POST["Country"];
$Company = $_POST["Company"];
$Telephone = $_POST["Telephone"];
$EMail = $_POST["EMail"];
$When_need_limo = $_POST["When_need_limo"];

echo $name;
?>

Comment: Zack: Where should i place this "header('Location: thank_you.php')" in order to direct people to the thank you page once they filled the form?

or should i enter a different code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can see, your problem is with your PHP code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$Country = $_POST["Country"];
$Company = $_POST["Company"];
$Telephone = $_POST["Telephone"];
$EMail = $_POST["EMail"];
$When_need_limo = $_POST["When_need_limo"];
echo $name; 
?>
```

`$name` is pointing to a field that would have the `name` attribute = "name". However, in your HTML, `name` is "Name".  Thus, to make your PHP code reflect the name in your HTML, you need to change it to:

`$name = $_POST["Name"]`

Then, when you `echo $name`, it should show you whatever was entered in that field.

Additionally, `header('Location: thank_you.php')` is designed to redirect the user to a page called "thank_you.php." You have it in your HTML, meaning it will never run as PHP.

If you want this code to get executed, you would need to wrap it in PHP tags, like so:

```
<?php
header('Location: thank_you.php')
?>
```

It would also need to be in a PHP file. However, if you put in your results.php file, the browser will immediately redirect to thank_you.php before showing the results.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: so when a visitor enters his name, company name,etc... and clicks on "submit", he goes to the thank you page.

But where do the data entered show up? i tried a test and nothing shows on the file "requests.php".

Comment: When you submit the form, does the browser URL say thank_you.php or requests.php?

Comment: the data entered by the visitor should show up on the requests.php page, right?

Comment: would you like the url of the page with the form?

Comment: Get rid of your `header('Location: thank_you.php')` code.

Comment: ok done. funny, i did a submit test and was directed to the thank_you.php page still.

Comment: totally exhausted as this is quite late for me in canada. need to go rest. thank you so much Zach for your help and patience. i do hope we can solve this.

Comment: url with the post form is at: www.limousinesworld.com/contact_es.php

Comment: This because the the form from the link you sent me is `<form action="http://www.limousinesworld.com/thank_you.php"`, instead of requests.php

Comment: what do you mean Zack?

Comment: I see <form action="requests.php" method="POST"> on the url i sent.

Comment: maybe i just changed it this morning, cannot remember all changes i made!